# Matrix associated to a projection onto the plane $π$ with equation $x−y + 2z = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T \colon  \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation which projects vectors onto the plane $π$ with equation $x−y + 2z = 0$. Find a matrix $A$ such that $T = T_A$

My workings so far:

$$ A = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
T(e_1)&T(e_2)&T(e_3)
\end{bmatrix}\right).  $$

First I need to find $f_1,f_2$ that span the plane $\pi$ and they are orthogonal. So I chose

$$ f_1 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\1  
\\0
\end{bmatrix}\right),  f_2 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-1
\\1  
\\1
\end{bmatrix}\right). $$

Next I need to use this formula but I am not quite sure how to
$$T(u)= uf_1/[f_1f_1] f_1 + uf_2/[f_2f_2] f_2$$

Looking for some help with carrying out the rest of the problem. Sorry I did not know the proper formatting for the $T(u)$ formula

Comment: $(-1,1,0)$ is not in the plane.

Comment: you are right I made a mistake there

Comment: If you want to project over the plane you need to discard the perpendicular component. What if you try $T\vec{u}=\vec{u}-\dfrac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{n}|}\vec{n}$ where $\vec{n}$ is a vector normal to the plane?

Comment: not quite sure how to do that

Comment: I have made a edit to $f_2$ so now it should be in the plane

Comment: What is the projection of a vector over $\vec{n}=(1,-1,2)?$ This is the part you need to vanish. So, once way is to get $T\vec{u}=\vec{u}-\dfrac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{u}||\vec{n}|}\vec{n}$ in an orthonormal basis. Other possibility is the one you are following. To get $A$ just write $T$ in an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @ mfl what is u in this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$ T \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \frac{\left< \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right>}{\left \| \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right \|^2 }\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  +  \frac{\left< \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right>}{\left \| \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right \|^2 }\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{x+y}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \frac{-x + y + z}{3} \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
= x \begin{pmatrix} \frac{5}{6} \\ \frac{1}{6} \\ -\frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix} + y \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{6} \\ \frac{5}{6} \\ \frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix} + z \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \frac{5}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{6} & \frac{1}{3} \\ -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}}_{A} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}.   $$

Comment: @ levap I am not quite understanding this formula $$T(u)= uf_1/[f_1f_1] f_1 + uf_2/[f_2f_2] f_2$$ what is u? I know you dot u with f1 then divided it by f1 dotted with f1 then you dot that whole thing with f1

Comment: @geohelp: I didn't edit your formula because I don't understand your notation. If you denote by $\left< v, w \right>$ the inner product of $v$ and $w$ (also know as the dot product), then in order to write a formula for the orthogonal projection of a vector $u$ on a two-dimensional subspace $W$, you need to find two orthogonal vectors $f_1,f_2$ that span $W$ and then the formula for the projection is $T(u) = \frac{\left< u, f_1 \right>}{||f_1||^2} f_1 + \frac{\left< u, f_2 \right>}{||f_2||^2} f_2$ (where $||f_i||^2 = \left< f_i, f_i \right>$ is the length squared of the vector $f_i$).

Comment: @ levap okay so what is u then? how do I solve <u,f1>?

Comment: @geohelp: $u$ is a vector in your vector space (here, in $\mathbb{R}^3$). If you work in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the standard inner product of two vectors $u = (x_1, \dots, x_n)^T$ and $v = (y_1, \dots, y_n)^T$ is given by $\left< u, v \right> = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$ (that is, you multiply the first coordinates of $u$ and $v$, then multiply the second coordinates of $u$ and $v$, etc, then add everything up).

Comment: I need to find $T(e_1)$, $T(e_2)$,$T(e_3)$

Comment: but what is u and v? is u 1 -1 2 from the question?

Comment: @geohelp: You don't **need** to find $T(e_i)$ to solve the question but you can find them and use your formula if you want. Just compute $T(e_i) = \frac{ \left< e_i, f_1 \right>}{||f_1||^2} f_1 + \frac{ \left< e_i, f_2 \right>}{||f_2||^2} f_2$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$.

Comment: @ levap yes that Is the formula I am trying to use, so in this case what is $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$? sorry for the confusion

Comment: @geohelp: For example, $T(e_1) = \frac{\left< (1,0,0)^T, (1,1,0)^T \right>}{\| (1,1,0)^T \|^2} (1,1,0)^T + \frac{ \left< (1,0,0)^T, (-1,1,1)^T \right>}{\| (-1,1,1)^T \|^2} (-1,1,1)^T = \frac{1}{2} (1,1,0)^T - \frac{1}{3} (-1,1,1)^T = (\frac{5}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, -\frac{1}{3})^T$.

Comment: @geohelp: $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are the standard basis vectors... $e_1 = (1,0,0)^T, e_2 = (0,1,0)^T, e_3 = (0,0,1)^T$.

Comment: @ levap okay so how do you calculate <(1,0,0),(1,1,0)> are those two things being dotted with each other? so the answer would be 1?

Comment: @geohelp: Yes, $\left< (1,0,0)^T, (1,1,0)^T \right> = 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 0 = 1$.

Comment: @ levap awesome I finally understand, thanks so much for your time